# Android. Я пытаюсь получить ID drawable-ресурса по его имени, но вместо ID возвращается 0

Tags: android, picasso, android-resources

P.S. ID нужен, чтобы отобразить картинку через библиотеку `Picasso`:

`Picasso.get().load(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("red_brick.png", "drawable", getPackageName())).into(imageView);`

Картинка `red_brick.png` лежит в папке drawable!

Comment: зачем, если можно просто `R.drawable.red_brick`?

Comment: @IR42 red_brick для примера, в реальном коде строковая переменная с именем файла

Comment: вместо "red_brick.png" должно быть "red_brick", без всяких расширений

Comment: И Picasso в данном конкретном случае абсолютно лишний.

Comment: Почему лишний? Так же удобнее картинку грузить